# Firewall configuration

Tags: ports

ALL,

I used to be a happy user of ZoneAlarm. However recently I needed to open a port on one of my machine (Windows 8.1, port 1433 for SQL Server) and I found out that this is apparently an impossible task. So, I asked and was told to use CoMoDo.

I did download and installed it, but now it looks like I still can't remotely access the server. Both CoMoDo and Windows FW are active and I thought that I did open the port in question on both of them. However, trying to telnet to the machine to port 1433 results in "Connection timed out".

And so, my question is - how do I properly open a port in both Windows 8.1 FW and CoMoDo FW?

I should also add that this is for my local LAN at home.

Thank you.

[EDIT]

Here is the output of some troubleshooting steps I did after following up from the answe I got.

```
C:\Users\Igor\Desktop>netstat -na | find "1433"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1433           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.1.4:1433       192.168.1.4:55788      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.4:55788      192.168.1.4:1433       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    [::]:1433              [::]:0                 LISTENING

igor@IgorDellGentoo ~/dbhandler $ nmap -v -p1433 192.168.1.4

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-06-24 23:09 EDT
Initiating Ping Scan at 23:09
Scanning 192.168.1.4 [2 ports]
Completed Ping Scan at 23:09, 3.00s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.4 [host down]
Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.15 seconds
igor@IgorDellGentoo ~/dbhandler $ nmap -v -p1433 192.168.1.1

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-06-24 23:10 EDT
Initiating Ping Scan at 23:10
Scanning 192.168.1.1 [2 ports]
Completed Ping Scan at 23:10, 0.04s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 23:10
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 23:10, 0.03s elapsed
Initiating Connect Scan at 23:10
Scanning 192.168.1.1 [1 port]
Completed Connect Scan at 23:10, 0.01s elapsed (1 total ports)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
Host is up (0.035s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
1433/tcp closed ms-sql-s

Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.14 seconds
igor@IgorDellGentoo ~/dbhandler $ ping -c 3 192.168.1.4
PING 192.168.1.4 (192.168.1.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=58.4 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=6.63 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.4: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=3.79 ms

--- 192.168.1.4 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.794/22.975/58.493/25.141 ms

igor@IgorDellGentoo ~/wxFork/buildGTK2/samples/listctrl $ busybox telnet 192.168.1.4 1433
telnet: can't connect to remote host (192.168.1.4): Connection timed out

IgorDellGentoo dbhandler # tcpdump -ni wlan0 host 192.168.1.4
dropped privs to tcpdump
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlan0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
23:20:02.159167 IP 192.168.1.2.47013 > 192.168.1.4.1433: Flags [S], seq 691635572, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1402552123 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
23:20:03.159796 IP 192.168.1.2.47013 > 192.168.1.4.1433: Flags [S], seq 691635572, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1402553124 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
23:20:05.163791 IP 192.168.1.2.47013 > 192.168.1.4.1433: Flags [S], seq 691635572, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1402555128 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
23:20:07.171775 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.4 tell 192.168.1.2, length 28
23:20:07.176715 ARP, Reply 192.168.1.4 is-at ac:b5:7d:e8:72:b7, length 28
23:20:09.171794 IP 192.168.1.2.47013 > 192.168.1.4.1433: Flags [S], seq 691635572, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1402559136 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
23:20:17.187794 IP 192.168.1.2.47013 > 192.168.1.4.1433: Flags [S], seq 691635572, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1402567152 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
23:20:33.203776 IP 192.168.1.2.47013 > 192.168.1.4.1433: Flags [S], seq 691635572, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1402583168 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
23:21:05.267791 IP 192.168.1.2.47013 > 192.168.1.4.1433: Flags [S], seq 691635572, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1402615232 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
23:21:10.275756 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.4 tell 192.168.1.2, length 28
23:21:10.282680 ARP, Reply 192.168.1.4 is-at ac:b5:7d:e8:72:b7, length 28
23:21:43.253368 IP 192.168.1.4 > 224.0.0.22: igmp v3 report, 1 group record(s)
23:21:45.301655 IP 192.168.1.4 > 224.0.0.22: igmp v3 report, 1 group record(s)
^C
13 packets captured
13 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

[/EDIT]

Comment: Have you opened/port forwarded from your router? E.g. Internet --> yourRouter (open/forward this port) --> Your machine?

Comment: @RobertMennell: ServerFault is dedicated to business environments. Question about consumer networks and workstation should be redirected to SuperUser instead (see [ServerFault topic page](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: Igor, welcome on Security SE. This question seems very specific to the use of customers tools. Such questions are usually more appropriate on [su] (normally given enough votes this question should be automatically redirected, so you should have nothing to do).

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf, what do you mean by "to the use of customers tools"? I'm using Windows FW in 8.1 and it is an OS tool not mine.

Comment: @munkeyoto, do I need to? I thought I should do that only when trying to access something on the web or get a response from the web to the specific port on local machine.

Comment: @Igor: I do not mean "self-made" tool ;) ! I mean customer tool as opposed as corporate tools. You are not setting up an ASA firewall with VPN authentication based on the corporate Domain Server with workstation compliance enforcement. This is the kind of issue ServerFault people are dealing with, and they expect to talk with professional system administrators (or similar proficiency level). At he opposite, on SuperUser are handled all the trouble you may have with your home computing system, including Windows unwilligness ;) . I hope I made myself clearer :) !

Comment: @Igor, yes, you need to open the port in your home router (if you have one), otherwise the router will act just like a firewall and will not allow external-to-your-LAN connections to initialize.

Comment: @Overmind, which port should I open on the router? The standard TCP ones are opened as I can talk to the web just fine. And I can even ping.

Comment: Talking to the web does not require forwarded ports. Ports can have 3 states: blocked - nothing goes through in any way; normal -you can connect to web, but external connections cannot start to you; forwarded - you can initialize and connect both ways. For everything to be good, you should forward both TCP/UDP 1433 and 1434. 1954 TCP may also be used by SQL SDBE.

Answer (score 0):

For everything to be good, you should forward both TCP/UDP 1433 and 1434. 1954 TCP may also be used by SQL SDBE.

Open those in your router and firewalls by creating a custom rule.
When you add a port to the rules list, you must specify the protocol and port number. When creating a port rule, you can specify TCP and UDP ports only, which is enough for what you need.

Practically:

- Open Windows Firewall
- Click Advanced settings. You might be asked for an admin password or to confirm your access.
- In the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security dialogue box, in the left pane, click Inbound Rules, then, in the right pane, tap or click New Rule.
- Follow the instructions on your screen to add one of the ports I specified and repeat for the others.

For Comodo:

Firewall->Advanced->Network Security Policy->Global Rules. Select Add, then add  rules for each port:

Action: Allow

Protocol: TCP

Direction: In/Out

Source Address: Any

Destination Address: Any

Source port: Any

Destination Port: 1433

Repeat for all.

Comment: I did that. I edited the question with some test output. Could you please check that? Thx

Comment: The port is is listening mode, which is good. Also, there's an established connection, also good. What router are you using ? If you have an avaliable windows station, just make a new empty file and call it test.udl. Double click it and a window will appear. There, you can put the sql server address and use the 'test connection' button to test the connectivity to the SQL.